# Explaining path used in SFTP file transfer using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

```
public static void sftpFile( String localDir, 
        String localFileName,
        String localAbsoluteFileName,
        String targetHost, 
        int targetPort,
        String targetDir,
        String identityFile,
        String targetUserId, 
        String targetPassword) throws ErrorCodeException
{

    Session session = null;
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
    JSch jsch = new JSch();        
    try
    {
        session = jsch.getSession( targetUserId, targetHost, targetPort );
        session.setConfig( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );

        if( identityFile != null )
        {
            jsch.addIdentity( identityFile );
        }

        if( targetPassword != null )
        {
            session.setPassword( targetPassword );
        }

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
        channel.connect();
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftpChannel.cd( targetDir );
        sftpChannel.lcd( localDir );

        sftpChannel.get( localAbsoluteFileName, "." );
        if( log.isTraceEnabled() )
        {
            log.trace( tracePrefix + localFileName + ": Done SFTP" );
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( "Error connecting to target host." );
        throw new ErrorCodeException(ErrorCode.COMMUNICATION_FAILURE);
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( sftpChannel != null )
        {
            sftpChannel.exit();
        }
        if ( session != null )
        {
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

I do not have a clear view of the following terms

- localDir
- targetDir
- localFileName
- localAbsoluteFileName

I want to transfer a file `test.csv` from server to client, opening SFTP channel from client.

File is at the following location in server "10.10.20.30"

```
/ram/server/files/test.csv
```

which needs to copied to the following location in client "10.10.20.40"

```
/ram/client/files
```

what is `localDir`, `targetDir`, `localFileName`, `localAbsoluteFileName` here
and what does the following steps does

```
sftpChannel.cd( targetDir );
sftpChannel.lcd( localDir );
```

Answer (score 3):

- `localDir` - The local working directory. The code uses a relative destination path (the `.`), which is resolved relatively to the local working directory. As the relative path is "this path" (the dot), you effectively download the file to the `localDir`. You should set this to `/ram/client/files`.
- `targetDir` - The remote working directory. If the `localAbsoluteFileName` is really absolute, the remote working directory is irrelevant. Either remove the use (the `.cd` call) or, if you do not want to change the implementation, set it to the `/ram/server/files` (or any other path you have an access to). Despite the name ("target"), it would actually be a source directory, if it were used.
- `localFileName` - Used for logging only.
- `localAbsoluteFileName` - Despite the "local" in the name, it used as a source path to the *remote* file to download. You should set this to `/ram/server/files/test.csv`.

Generally the naming of the parameters seems wrong. It looks like someone took uploading code, changed it to downloading code (replacing a `.put` with the `.get`), while keeping the parameter naming used for the upload.